# Core Data one-to-many relation saving entity confusion

Tags: ios, core-data

I am working on a project where I am using core data, but bit confused how to use it corectly.

I have two entities students and college

students has one-to-one relationship to college. That is every student will have one college.
college has one-to-many relationship to student. that is college can have lot's of students.

However, in my app I am letting the user to add the student first without any college info. So I am keeping the relationship to college optional. In a 2nd view, I let the user update the college information of a student.

Now I am while adding a new student I am just updating the basic field related to student (firs name, last name, age, etc.). Now in 2nd view while updating college info I am not sure what is the correct way to do it considering the relationship.

The first view pass the student object to 2nd view and I am updating it as  follows:

```
College* college = (College*)[NSEntityDescription    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"College" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

college.name = @"name"
college.address = @"address"
[college addStudentObject:self.student];
```

Am I doing it correctly? 
what should be the correct way:

1. Adding the college object in 2nd view and connecting the entity by adding the student object in the student relation of a college?
2. Retrieving the student object first then getting the empty college object from the college relation. Then updating the college object with data and then save the context.

I am not sure if the 2nd option make any sense but in case of first option, if I add a new college, the new college get connected with the  student but the old college remain in the database as redundant data.

Comment: What happens if the college already exists (for that name and address) in the MOC? Option 2 doesn't make sense as there is no empty college, there is just `nil`.

Comment: Just checked it is adding it anyway. So if I retrieve the list of College it shows two entry with same name and address.

Comment: So you should add some UI for choosing an existing college / choosing to add a new one. Then, connect the student to that selected / new college.

Comment: @Wain, I understand that I can let the user choose from existing college or add a new one. But how should I update an existing college? For example, the user has partially completed the  college form and wants to update it later. In this scenario, i need fetch the existing college which is already connected with the student and let the user update remaining feild.

Comment: If the college is connected to the student already then you can use the relationship (it should be a single relationship with the inverse properly set).

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I would probably create another entity, StudentEnrollment with one to one relationship to both student and college. It would probably make it easier to manage student's courses, grades, etc as well as transfers to another college.